# How do I use LINQ to combine these two methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, linq

I have these methods below. Which one is a list of collection and another one is not a list

```
public List<GithubItem> Build(string input)
{
    var getData = GetGithubRepos(input);
    return System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<GithubItem>>(getData);
}

public GithubUser BuildPerson(string input)
{
    var getData = GetGithubPerson(input);
    return System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<GithubUser>(getData);
}
```

Now, I want to use LINQ query to combine both of the objects and select only what I need out of both.

```
public List<GithubCustomApi> requestAPi(string input)
{
    List<GithubItem> repo = Build(input);
    GithubUser user = BuildPerson(input);

    /////////////////////////////////////
    //I want something like this below//

    var stringQuery = SELECT repo.*, user.* from repo  where repo.owner.id = user.id
    var linqQuery = from c in stringQuery select new GithubCustomApi() { fullname = c.full_name, email = c.emial ...}

    /////////////////////////////////////
    return linqQuery;
}
```

I want something like this where I can combine both and then full the data matching what I have in my class `GithubCustomApi()`. Can someone help please?

Thank you

Comment: Not conpletely sure if this is what you want since the question is not that clear to me. Could you be looking for: `repo.Where(r => r.owner.id == user.id).Select(r => new GitHubCustomApi { fullname = user.full_name, url = r.url }).ToList();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
public List<GithubCustomApi> requestAPi(string input)
{
    List<GithubItem> repo = Build(input);
    GithubUser user = BuildPerson(input);

    var userRepos = repo
                       .Where(x => x.owner.id == user.id)
                       .Select(x => new GithubCustomApi { fullname = user.full_name, email = user.email, userRepo = x, ...})
                       .ToList();
    return userRepos;
}
```